# Is every polynomial $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ primitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Disclaimer: from an engineer.

I’m just working with polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, and I want to use some results related to squarefree factorisation. All the useful results are stated for primitive polynomials in UFDs.
My references don’t define primitive, and when I go hunting in books, I seem to come up with conflicting definitions:

Winkler states that a polynomial $p \in I[x]$, where $I$ is a UFD, is primitive if there is no prime in $I$ that divides all of its coefficients. Since a field has no primes, I conclude that all polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are primitive.

But Geddes et al suggest that if a polynomial in a UFD has only one nonzero term, it is primitive iff it is monic.

Are there multiple definitions of primitive, or have I misunderstood something?
Can someone please tell me what the primitive polynomials are over the reals, in the context of squarefree factorisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (always with $1$). Let $p(x)=a_0+a_1x + \ldots +a_nx^n$ be a polynomial of degree at most $n$ with coefficients from $R$. Then we say $p$ is primitive if and only if there exist $c_0,c_1 ,\ldots,c_n $ in $R$ such that
$$a_0c_0+a_1 c_1 +\ldots + a_n c_n =1.$$
Then over a  Bezout domain, a polynomial is primitive iff the GCD of the coefficients is $1$, and in a UFD, a nonzero polynomial is primitive iff no prime divides every coefficient. (The zero polynomial is not primitive over any nontrivial ring.) Over any commutative ring, a monomial is primitive iff its coefficient is invertible. Finally, a polynomial over a field is primitive iff it is nonzero (so you should be sure you're not really interested in, say, its ring of integers).

Comment: Thanks @K B Dave, Could you recommend a reference that might include these?